# How do I remove MyRadRails from my eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse, radrails

I am a newbie to Eclipse, how do I remove MyRadRails from my eclipse installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install that via '**Install New software...**'?

If so, you could uninstall it via '**Help**' - '**About**' - '**Installation Details**', select your installed features to uninstall.

If you downloaded the plug-ins, then copy them into your eclipse. You could delete those plug-in directly.